# Unpinned messages stay starred

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins, room-owner

I just ran across a bug in chat.  If you are the room owner, you have the ability to pin/unpin messages.  However, recently I ran a test (in my own private chat-room, don't worry! :) ) to see how many messages I could pin and what happens if I ran over the limit.  However, I ran across a bug which we verified in another room.  When you remove the pin from the message, it remains starred, even if the pinner was the poster of the message.

[image]

A friend tried the same thing, but with a single message in a chatroom he owns, and it appears that it is a reproducable bug.  Would appreciate some help on it!